# Attempting to discover unicode code point for a character

Tags: unicode, binary, utf-16

I have a character that when viewed in a hex editor is shown as:

```
FF  FE  08  27
```

meaning it's binary representation is (a four byte encoding):

```
11111111
11111110
00001000
00100111
```

Looking at the unicode [table and description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) this doesn't seem to make sense, since a four byte encoding must have the leading byte in the form `11110xxx`.

I'm most likely misunderstanding the unicode rules, but could you please let me know where I'm going wrong in determining the code point for this character?

Comment: This is not [valid UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-8#Codepage_layout). It looks more like UTF-16.

Comment: I bit miffed as to the negative vote.

Comment: I rolled back your edit to my answer.  `U+FEFF` is correct and is the byte-order mark.  That your raw data has it reversed is what indicates little-endian.  The least significant byte is first. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Unicode character `U+FEFF` is the byte order mark (BOM) indicating this is little-endian UTF-16 encoding, not UTF-8.  The character is `U+2708`, or the `AIRPLANE`(✈️) character.

A little proof using Python 3:

```
>>> import unicodedata as ud
>>> s=b'\xff\xfe\x08\x27'
>>> s.decode('utf16')      # Removes BOM and uses indicated little-endian decode.
'\u2708'
>>> s.decode('utf-16le')   # explicit decode in little endian leaves BOM.
'\ufeff\u2708'
>>> for c in u: print(ud.name(c))
...
ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE  # also known as BOM.
AIRPLANE
```